# Im getting Error 'java.lang.String' and not knowing why

Tags: java

[image]I'm newbie in Java. So question might sound simple, but I'm stuck and can not figure out why I get the error java.lang.String although all I do is just write out the setter and getter normally. So below is my code:

```
    package PerSion;

public class Student extends Persion{
    String RollNum, Class;
    double Score;

    public String getRollNum() {
        return this.RollNum;
    }

    public void setRollNum(String RollNum) {
        this.RollNum = RollNum;
    }

    public String getClass() {  //this is where the error show up
        return this.Class;
    }

    public void setClass(String Class) {
        this.Class = Class;
    }

    public double getScore() {
        return this.Score;
    }

    public void setScore(double Score) {
        this.Score = Score;
    }

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String RollNum, String Class, double Score) {
        this.RollNum = RollNum;
        this.Class = Class;
        this.Score = Score;
    }

    public Student(String RollNum, String Class, double Score, String ID, String Name, String Address, int Age) {
        super(ID, Name, Address, Age);
        this.RollNum = RollNum;
        this.Class = Class;
        this.Score = Score;
    }

    @Override
    public void Display() {
        System.out.println(RollNum+"\t"+Name+"\t"+Class+"\t"+Score);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "the error java.lang.String " is not the full error message. Where do you see this? Please [edit] your question with the full error message.

Comment: I see there is a red squiggly that indicates an error. But the popup shows documentation, not an error. You need to figure out how to get the actual error message. One way is to compile your program.

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't allow me to compile and run"? What didn't allow this? There is definitely an error. You don't need to assume. The red squiggly means there is an error, but the screenshot doesn't show what the error is.

Comment: What editor are you using? And how did you try to compile your code?

Comment: i mean my code is not functioning. sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Don't apologize. We all started somewhere. However, you need to be more specific. "my code is not functioning" doesn't provide the information I need to help you. Be sure you read all my previous comments and answer my questions in as much detail as you can. Refresh the page to be sure you get the most recent version of this page and comments.

Comment: I suspect that the answer from Dawood ibn Kareem will solve the problem, but I'd also like to help you to get further by yourself next time an error occurs. Because it will happen again and again as long as you continue coding.

Comment: @Bohemian sorry i havent use stack for a long time so theres still something that im not really aware of. i will keep this in mind on my next time posting a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that every class already has a `final` method called `getClass`.  You'll have to call your one something else, because you can't have two methods with the exact same name and same parameters in a class, and you can't override a `final` method.